Android Studio Does Not Accept my Implementations
I just installed Android Studio Iguana and I am new to Android Studio, so I don't know why this is happening. I want to install on my dependency the ML Kit of Google:
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to use the dynamically downloaded model in Google Play Services
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.3.0'
}


However, I am surprised that my dependencies looks like this:
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

Therefore, when I write these implementations, the one in '' marks, it does not work and gives me an error. What should I do here?

It is because of recent changes done by android.

when you create new project it will ask "Build configuration language" which is set to kotln DSL by defualt. which means now build.gradle file will be kotlin file named build.gradle.kts.
In which adding new dependency will be done like this

implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.3.0")
please read some articles about kotlin dsl file vs groovy dsl (build.gradle)

implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
you are wondering about this kind of implementation, it is because now your dependency is written in libs.versions.toml file which is located in {project}/gradle folder.
it is a version catalog file that helps you centralize your dependency, please find an article about it, it is very helpful.

even if you don't want to write your dependency like this, you may still write your dependency like in 1st point.

thank you so much! This solves the problem. I should read more of these that you have sent me. Seems like there's still a lot for me to go through to understand this. Again, thank you so much!

Would be better to add the dependency to the version catalog rather than adding it to the build file directly.
